# Default export in Python 3

Tags: python, django, python-3.5

In a project I'm working on, I'm separating a lot of bigger files into smaller pieces so they're easier to work with. One specific example is creating class based views from function based views in Django:

```
# app/views/LoginView.py
class LoginView(View):
  ...

# urls.py
from app.views import LoginView
urlpatterns = [
  # Here, I have to use LoginView twice
  url(r'^login', LoginView.LoginView.as_view())
]
```

Above, I have to use `LoginView` twice when I want to call it, since importing `LoginView` imports the module, and not the method from the module, even though they are the same name. Ideally, I'd like to avoid having to call `LoginView.LoginView` each time.

In Javascript, I can just say `export default function my_function() { ... }` without naming it, and when it's imported it's default, e.g `import my_function from './some_module.js';`

Is there any way to do something like this in Python 3? I do not want to do `from app.views.LoginView import LoginView` because, especially in a big Django project and in a file like `urls.py`, it isn't feasible to have each import on a separate line.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can import `LoginView` as a name under `app.views` using the `__init__.py` of `app.views`.

In `app/views/__init__.py`:

```
from LoginView import LoginView
```

In `urls.py`

```
import app.views 

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^login', app.views.LoginView.as_view())
]
```